# Отступ к блока с контентом, если к низу экрана прижат футер

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!

В верстке страницы футер прижат к низу экрана:

```
div.footer {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Контента на странице много и из-за свойства fixed у футера теперь часть контента не видна, т.к. она находится "ниже" футера. Как сделать отступ блока с контентом от низа экрана так, чтобы он не "залазил" за футер?

Спасибо.

Вот пример — http://jsfiddle.net/DYMWy/

Comment: Добавте контейнеру с контентом padding-bottom:30px(высота вашего футера),тогда текта под футером не будет

Comment: В таком случае отступ только в самом конце блока появляется.
Вот пример — http://jsfiddle.net/DYMWy/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DYMWy/4/ так ?

Comment: еще так можно, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DYMWy/5/ , но мне кажется это  хак какой-то.

Comment: eicto, спасибо, верно! Именно это и имелось ввиду, благодарен очень!

Не нашел где проголосовать за ответ и закрыть вопрос, все в виде комментариев показано.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два способа, оба на html5

первый используя псевдоэлемент :before

```
div.footer:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    content: '\0000a0';
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DYMWy/4/

второй, используя fixed и bottom:

```
div.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DYMWy/5/